# What's the spoken version of "same as above"?

Tags: phrase-request, spoken-english

Example:

> "Do you like Shiba Inus?"
>
> "Yes"
>
> "What about Chihuahuas?"
>
> "Same as above"

Obviously, you can't say same as above in spoken English, because ... well it sounds weird to me (I picture the listener staring at the sky).

Maybe I'm wrong? If not, what's the spoken version of the phrase?

Comment: **ditto** is another curt reply.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo this should be an answer. It's perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could say:

> "Likewise"

or

> "Them too"

Although both of these suggestions are short, casual answers, and in casual speech I would not be surprised to hear someone say "as above" or a variation of the phrase - while it is not strictly great English we sometimes use phrases out of context for humorous effect.